# What is the appropriate way of storing a game unit's attributes (cost)?

Tags: python

Lets say you have a game where you can train units which have a cost attached to them and you want to be a able to calculate the total cost of training a certain amount of said units.

The units all share the same attributes but the value of said attributes will change across the different units.

I have found 2 potential solutions, using dictionaries:

```
spearmen = {'gold' : 2, 'wood' : 10, 'stone' : 5, 'iron' : 0}
swordsmen = {'gold' : 5, 'wood' : 30, 'stone': 0, 'iron' : 10}
```

But I find the way to access the information to be a bit verbose:

```
swordsmen['gold'] * 1200
```

So I wondered if doing something like this would be appropriate:

```
class Spearmen:
    gold = 2
    wood = 10
    stone = 5
    iron = 0

class Swordsmen
    gold = 5
    wood = 30
    stone = 0
    iron = 10
```

Using classes makes accessing the information slightly less verbose:

```
Spearmen.gold * 1200
```

Doing some cursory research I found [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160675/what-do-you-call-classes-without-methods), which suggests that more often than not what I am trying to do is considered an anti pattern. So I am not sure about this solution either.

When thinking about the evolution of my program, it is highly unlikely that I will have to add new attributes to the units, but it is more likely than not that I will need to add new units (with the same attributes).

So I wonder if either of these solutions are appropriate or if there is a better way to do it (and why are they wrong).

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based, but my opinion is that you should create a class called `Unit`, for example, that defines an `__init__` method that takes `gold`, `wood`, `stone`, and `iron` as parameters and sets them all as attributes of the instance.  You could then say `spearmen = Unit(5, 30, 0, 10)` and use `spearman.gold * 1200`.  Since you are using just one class, you don't need to define a new one for each new kind of unit.

Comment: I'm voting this to close because opinion-based or for programmers site (which can't be selected in the dialog for other SE sites...)

Comment: Being a newbie I assumed I may have been committing a cardinal sin with either solution, but since this seems to be an opinion thing please do close the question, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes for objects should be part of the object definition (class). If the objects share a common set of attributes, they should be inherited from a parent class.

As to how you should store them, there are many ways to do this. You can have a parent class that defines the default attributes for a common object (as @zondo suggested, a *Unit* class); these attributes can be stored as a dictionary.

You can modify the dictionary in inherited classes to override the values of the default attributes *or create new ones for that specific unit type*.

```
class BaseUnit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, stats={}):
       self.stats = {}

       if not stats:
           self.stats['health'] = 10
           self.stats['armor'] = 10
           self.stats['strength'] = 10
       else:
           self.stats.update(stats)

       self.name = name

class Peon(BaseUnit):
    pass

class Warrior(BaseUnit):
    pass

grunt = Peon(name='Igor', {'strength': 5, 'armor': 5})
soldier = Warrior(name='Frank', {'armor': 10, 'health': 20, 'damage': 50})
```